# How to set up reactotron-apisauce in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native and reactotron.

I want to monitor axios HTTP request, but I can't.

In my idea, networking = XMLHttpRequests, apisauce = axios.
below is my code.

```
// Reactotron.config
import Reactotron, { networking } from 'reactotron-react-native'
import apisaucePlugin from 'reactotron-apisauce'

Reactotron
  .configure()
  .useReactNative(networking())
  .useReactNative(apisaucePlugin())
  .connect()

//App.js
import './config/ReactotronConfig';
import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-js'
// I tried import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native'

api.addMonitor(Reactotron.apisauce)
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If monitoring axios requests is the only purpose you want to solve.

I suggest you make your requests global.

Add this line in your `index.js` file.

`GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest || GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest;`

Now, on your emulator, enable `Debug JS Remotely`, there you can see all your network requests from the network tab.